# Extracting chinese data from rtf file content

Tags: c++, c, rtf

I have an rtf file which contains data below. encode mode is ansicpg1252.

\f2 \'98\'5f\'8c\'ea

which represents

論語

while parsing \' will let me know that data following this is hexadecimal value.

And another is

\f0\fs24 \cf0 \'91

which represents ' character.

How can i parse so that the character gets decked properly.

Regards,

Comment: You can find the RTF specification in http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=7105  It explains what all the \ codes mean.

Comment: Note that not all products return the same sequences in RTF (even MS doesn't generate the same sequences for different products). Easiest way is to write a state machine and gather up the different bits as they come in.  Don't assume any order.